# how to lock a picturebox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

In the old method in VB.net this was used to lock a picture box does anyone know the new method in VS 2012?

`PictureBox.locked = falese`

Comment: There was no `Locked` property in VB6 for a PictureBox control.  Are you referring to locking controls in the designer?

Comment: @LarsTech: OP did not reference VB6 anywhere.

Comment: @Neolisk I latched on to the phrase "In the old method".

Comment: no you can lock picture box in VB6 . The picture box was used a read only textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same, so you would set `PictureBox.Locked = False` in VS 2012 designer.

See [an article on MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80xxxf69%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is a screenshot from VS 2012, where I locked a PictureBox in brand new WinApp project.

[image]

Comment: but it is giving me an error which indicates that Locked is not apart of picturebox

Comment: Thanks alot i didnt know it was from the properties panel

Comment: @shaikibrahim: It is a designer-only property. It does not affect runtime behavior of controls.